# Moving makeup air ducting

Tags: hvac

Our makeup air system has a long, low hanging run that we'd like to move to create more headroom. Is there anything wrong with moving the current ducting (green in sketch) to attach to a return vent behind the main trunk (red)? The makeup air damper fits in the proposed spot.

Also, is it normal to have such large ducting for forced air heating/cooling (not the makeup air, but the 'trunks')?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your sketch seems to have gone AWOL. You can [edit] your question to try adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Trunks are normally quite large.

The only HVAC concern for moving the makeup air duct is to be sure the new location for the makeup air intake is not too close to some exhaust vent or other source of *not so fresh* makeup air.

There might be a *structural concern* of moving it from the not very structurally stressed rim joist between the ends of the floor joists (where the floor joists carry the wall load above) to a rim joist that is one (the last) of the load-bearing floor joists. It's a pretty big hole in a joist. It's being supported by the wall below, but it's supporting the wall above, so cutting a big hole in it is questionable.